# Consumption smoothing via Euler equation

Tags: macroeconomics, optimization

A representative cnsumer maximizes their lifetime utility function:
$$
U=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\beta^{t}\text{ln}\left(C_{t}\right)
$$
defined over consumption. They supply one unit of labour inelastically,
each period, and obtain a known sequence of wages, $w_{t}=w$, each
period. The agent faces budget constraint:
$$
P_{t}C_{t}+a_{t}\leq w_{t}+\left(1+r\right)a_{t-1}
$$
where $a_{t}$ represents the quantity of bond holdings purchased
at time $r,$ on which a return of $r$ units is obtained per $a_{t}$
and $P_{t}$ represents a change in the price of consumption. The
Euler equation is:
$$
\frac{1}{C_{t}}=\frac{\beta}{C_{t+1}}\left(\frac{P_{t}}{P_{t+1}}\right)\left(1+r_{t}\right)
$$
Imagine now, that at period $T$, wages drop to say 0 (i.e. the agent
does not receive any labour incme). Intuitively, given a discount
factor and positive interest rates, consumptions are linked across
periods through the Euler equation. Is there an obvious way to see
consumption smoothing in this case? For instance, imagine a case where
the individual was consuming all wealth in each period (i.e. maximizing
static utility only). Where/how can it be discerned that in the lifetime
utility case, the individual will have higher consumption in period
$T$ relative to the static utility case?